# How to change color of tabs in the tab-bar in gvim?

Tags: gvim, colorscheme, tabbed-user-interface

Here is what my tab-bar in GVim looks like:

[image]

I'm having a hard time to identify which of the tabs is the active one.

How can I configure the color of the tab-bar, for example I'd like to use a different color for the highlighted one, or for the others.

I found similar questions on the StackExchange-network:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65401/changing-color-of-tabs-titles-in-vim-color-files

However, the following code (from the question's answer)

```
:hi TabLineFill ctermfg=LightGreen ctermbg=DarkGreen
:hi TabLine ctermfg=Blue ctermbg=Yellow
:hi TabLineSel ctermfg=Red ctermbg=Yellow
```

changes nothing for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colors of the tabs follow the general color scheme configured on your system. The tabs should look similar to tabs in other programs.

Try changing the GTK theme on your system, for example using the `gnome-tweak-tool`. Or on Ubuntu, using `ubuntu-tweak`. See also: [How can you change the GTK Theme and Window Decorations separately in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/q/361422/255332)

Comment: I'm using Plasma/KDE on Debian. gnome-tweak-tool has no effect in my setup. Your answer is nevertheless correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the `e` flag from the `'guioptions'` option, this way the tab line matches the general colorscheme.

```
set guioptions-=e
```

Then use the `:highlight` command's GUI options, e.g.:

```
hi TabLine guifg=#fadfc2 guibg=#7d8e7b gui=underline
hi TabLineSel guifg=#ffffff guibg=#ef114a gui=bold,italic
hi TabLineFill guifg=#2dbd1e guibg=#ffffff
```

Conveniently, you can add that to your "gvimrc" file.

Note: I use gVim in Windows 10 with the 9.0 version.